# How do I programmatically execute an event?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to trigger event in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Such as a click event, or an onmouseover event. Is there some type of way to initiate all kinds of events programmatically, and how?

Answer (score 1):

Basically like that `document.getElementById('searchSubmit').click();`